# Android Studio 3.1 Updating indices after every build

Tags: android, android-studio

I've experiencing a weird behavior from Android Studio 3.1. Every time I run my app, Studio start updating indices after every build, which means its invalidates the old indices or something.Major downside to this is no able to change code while its building and extra time loss because of the update after every build.
I have searched it but couldn't find anything. And this is happening on all our development machines so I guess it's Android Studio's issue.